# Not able to install/uninstall packages using python pip

Tags: python, pip, macos-sierra

When I tried to install or uninstall packages using pip(with or without using sudo), I am getting Exception.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-gpvJsN-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

My OS is MacOS Sierra. I have tried to uninstall and install pip, but the problem still exists. Please help.

Comment: Do you have tried to uninstall/install Python?

Comment: No. I will try that. There is no other way other than that?

Comment: Exactly, I could not able to confirm. However, reinstall may solve missing components issues.

Comment: Now I am able to install packages, but previously existing packages cannot uninstall. I installed pip using `easy_install pip`, then I installed packages with command `--user`.

Comment: You should custom download the python since the built in python for Mac is terrible

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your questions seems to be missing some vital information for it does not state the exact command you use to try and install a python module using pip. Please always try to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If I'd have to take a guess by the error-code however, I would guess you are facing a permission/rights issue rather then a pip-issue. I see 2 clues that make me suspect such a thing. For 1: `[Errno 1]` usually means there is a permission error and 2: you mention in your comments that you installed packages using `--user`, but did you use that when trying to uninstall them as well?